# Некрасивый вывод в консоль

Tags: c++, binary

можете подсказать как подредактировать функцию , которая выводит бинарное  дерево поиска , просто в моем выводе в консоль не совсем понятно к какому узлу принадлежит тот или иной подузел , можно ли как то подправить эту функцию , чтобы в выводе было понятно , какие подузлы какому узлу принадлежат? (кол-во элементов дерева заранее известно) Дерево в моей программе поворачивается на 90 градусов влево

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <stack>
using namespace std;
int tabs = 0;
struct Node
{
    int x;
    Node *xLeft, *xRight;
};

void Print(Node* q)
{
    if (!q) return;
    tabs += 6;

    Print(q->xRight);
        for (int i = 0; i < tabs; i++) cout << "  ";
        cout << q->x << endl<<endl;

    Print(q->xLeft);

    tabs -= 6;
    return;
}

void CheckOnSimilarity(int* elements, int& index, int k)// устранение одинаковых элементов массива
{
    for (int i = 0; i < index; i++)
    {
        while (elements[i] == k)// до тех пор , пока j-ый эл-т равен хотя бы одному предшествующему эл-ту 
        {// рандомизировать до того момента , когда он будет отличаться
            k = 100 + rand() % 899;
        }
    }
}
void addNode(int x, Node*& MyTree)
{
    if (MyTree == nullptr)
    {
        MyTree = new Node;
        MyTree->x = x;
        MyTree->xLeft = MyTree->xRight = nullptr;
        return;
    }
    else
    {//Иначе сверим вносимое
        if (MyTree->x > x)
        { //Если оно меньше того, что в этой ветке - добавим влево
            addNode(x, MyTree->xLeft);
        }
        else
        { //Иначе в ветку справа
            addNode(x, MyTree->xRight);
        };
    }

}


void ShowRevRLN(Node*& MyTree, int*& showRLN, const int& amount)
{
    if (!MyTree) return;

    if (MyTree == nullptr) return;    //Если дерева нет, выходим

    ShowRevRLN(MyTree->xRight, showRLN, amount);
    ShowRevRLN(MyTree->xLeft, showRLN, amount); //Обошли левое поддерево 
    cout << MyTree->x << " "; //Посетили узел 

}
void del(Node*& Tree)
{
    if (Tree != NULL)
    {
        del(Tree->xLeft);
        del(Tree->xRight);
        delete Tree;
        Tree = nullptr;
    }
}
int main()
{
    // сгенерировать 25 неповторяющихся чисел
    // вывести их на экран 
    //построить поисковое дерево
    //вывести на экран это дерево
    //вывести на экран последовательность вершин, соответсвующую обратному прохождению дерева с приоретом направо
    Node* Tree = nullptr;
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "RUS");

    srand(time(NULL));
    int amount = 25;// по заданию
    int* elements = new int[amount];//массив для трехзначных чисел
    int* showRLN = new int[amount];//создаем массив для вывода последовательности вершил

    for (int i = 0; i < amount; i++)
    {
        elements[i] = 100 + rand() % 899;
        CheckOnSimilarity(elements, i, elements[i]);
    }
    cout << "Последовательность чисел: ";
    for (int i = 0; i < amount; i++)
    {
        if (i != amount - 1)
            cout << elements[i] << " " << ", ";
        else
            cout << elements[i];
    }
    
    cout << endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < amount; i++)
    {
        addNode(elements[i], Tree);
    }

    cout << endl;
    cout << "Двоичное дерево поиска" << endl;
    cout << endl;
    Print(Tree);
    
    cout << endl;

    cout << "Последовательность вершин, соответсвующая RLN : ";
    ShowRevRLN(Tree, showRLN, amount);

    del(Tree);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Всё и так уже рабочее, достаточно чуть-чуть подкорректировать....

1. избавиться от переменной tabs - она мало того, что глобальная (выгодней делать статической внутри функции Print), так ещё и не нужна;
2. добавляем в функцию Print() ещё один параметр int level=0, который будет уровни определять рекурсивно;
3. уменьшить количество выводимых пробелов, чтобы получилось компактней;
4. если хочется - можно выводить какой-нибудь символ в случае, когда ветка пустая.

```
void Print(const Node* node, int level=0)
{
    if (node == nullptr)
    {
        // если требуется вывод пустого узла 
        // for (int i = 0; i < level; ++i)
        //    std::cout << "    ";
        // std::cout << "¤" << std::endl;
        return;
    }
    Print(node->right, level + 1);
    for (int i = 0; i < level; ++i)
        std::cout << "    ";
    std::cout << node->data << std::endl;
    Print(node->left, level + 1);
}
```

Вызов из main() не изменится.
Если хочется, чтобы просматривались уровни - можно в строку из пробелов добавить палочку `"   |"`.